# Android project library not refreshing?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an Android Project which I've converted to a Library (properties > Android > Library > Is Library) and am using in a different project (Properties > Android > Library > Add ...). I applied some updates yesterday and progard.cfg in the Project Library is now tagged with the error "Obsolete proguard file; use -keepclasseswithmembers instead of -keepclasseswithmembernames". I've refreshed the PL and edited proguard but still the errors remained until I completely deleted the contents of proguard, saved it, then pasted the contents back in. I've also noticed the PL R.java seems to get out of whack at times and cleaning and refreshing do nothing until I uncheck the "Is Library" property and then do a clean/refresh.

Are these issues due to something I'm missing in my project properties or preferences? Would be nice if I could get it to refresh and not have to keep messing with that checkbox.

Comment: I have a similar issue with a project that uses 3 android Library when I start eclipse or perform a clean on project and libraries, I get build path errors . I have to go in the bin project of the library and refresh it so eclipse realize that the .jar is there .

Concerning libraries I don't use any special settings just the "is Library" .

Comment: Seems like something weird with Eclipse. Refresh on bin/ does not work for me but thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try to go at build configurations, click in the project tab, add your project library, then go to the "Order and export" tab, put on the top your library project and check it. One last thing, clean and give a try.